Statement clarification: When do we have $\Delta = \frac{d-1}{2} q_R$?
This statement is for SCFT, where $\Delta$ is the conformal weight, $q_R$ is the R-charge. How many supersymmetries do we need? Do we need chiral primary scalar, or just chiral scalar? How to derive it?

These questions should be answered in https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00809
